# MySQL importing a CSV converting the date format

Tags: mysql, date, csv

I'm importing data from a `csv` to a `MySQL` table. I need to convert the date format from `String` to `Date`. 
From Starting format to finale format:

```
Mon Feb 04 00:00:00 UTC 2011  ---> 2011-02-04 00:00:00
```

I've done it sucessfully:

```
select str_to_date('Mon Feb 04 00:00:00 UTC 2011', '%a %b %d %k:%i:%s UTC %Y');
```

Now I'm writing the script to do all the import from the `csv`, there are 2 columns with the date to be converted, but I'm stuck with a `MySQL` syntax exception on the `set` part.

My `SQL` script:

```
load data local infile 'movimento.csv' into table movimento
fields terminated by ',' lines terminated by '\n'
(id, anno, creditore, @data_pag, @data_spost, descrizione)
set data_pagamento = str_to_date(@data_pag, '%a %b %d %k:%i:%s UTC %Y')
set data_spostamento = str_to_date(@data_spost, '%a %b %d %k:%i:%s UTC %Y')
show warnings;
```

I'm stuck with a syntax exception on the `set` part. The error:

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'set data_spostamento = str_to_date(@data_spost, '%a %b %d %k:%i:%s UTC %Y')
show' at line 5
>

What's the right syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is incorrect. Try this one -

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'movimento.csv' INTO TABLE movimento
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(ID, anno, creditore, @data_pag, @data_spost, descrizione)
SET
  data_pagamento = STR_TO_DATE(@data_pag, '%a %b %d %k:%i:%s UTC %Y'),
  data_spostamento = STR_TO_DATE(@data_spost, '%a %b %d %k:%i:%s UTC %Y')
```