# How to insert this date (2-3-2017 00:00:00) in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a CSV excel file that I want to insert in my `MySQL` database...but it's giving me an error code on my date.

Dates-Excel :

[image]

Error-code-MySQL :

[image]

I have tried to set my date in `MySQL` to `datetime` but that doesn't work...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL importing a CSV converting the date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680380/mysql-importing-a-csv-converting-the-date-format)

Answer (score 2):

you can use str_to_date() function

```
select str_to_date('2-3-2017','%d-%m-%YYYY')
```

Comment: In which kind of field do I need to store that information? varchar?

Comment: @Rob, yes you can use varchar